# Put an image before references in paper

Tags: floats, positioning

I have written the following code

```
\newpage
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=\textheight]{my_fig}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{fig:my_fig}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{splncs03}
\bibliography{my_bib}
```

The image covers an entire page. When I compile my document, the image comes after the bibliography and I receive the following warning

```
LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 22.75pt on input line 221
```

I want the image to be put right before the bibliography. How can I do it? I already tried with the options `[h]` and `[!h]`. Consider also that I am using the `llncs` style.

Comment: If you want to place a picture **exactly** in one point, you shouldn't use the `figure` environment. Furthermore you should reduce your image size since it's too large for the page

Comment: The `\textheight` specification is too large since there's no space left for the caption box height

Comment: Use \clearpage instead of \newpage if you want to ensure that floats are output before the following text.

Answer (score 1):

I corrected the image height putting `[height=0.95\textheight]`, and I added `[!h]`. Now it has been placed correctly.